# How to Label only Certain Vertices in a Network Based on Eigenvector Centrality?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, data, labeling, data-structures

Using the Following Network:

```
footballNetwork = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "AmericanCollegeFootball"}];
Graph[footballNetwork, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

---

I ranked the top ten nodes based on `EigenvectorCentrality`, and highlighted those nodes on the network:

```
HighlightGraph[footballNetwork, Part[VertexList[footballNetwork], Ordering[EigenvectorCentrality[footballNetwork], -10]]]
```

[image]

---

I know how to label all of the nodes in the network, but how do I label ***only*** the nodes that are highlighted?

Comment: If `ord = Ordering[EigenvectorCentrality[footballNetwork], -10]` with `Graph[footballNetwork, 
 VertexLabels -> 
  Thread[VertexList[footballNetwork][[ord]] -> 
    VertexList[footballNetwork][[ord]]]]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
t10 = VertexList[footballNetwork][[Ordering[EigenvectorCentrality[footballNetwork], -10]]];

HighlightGraph[footballNetwork, Property[#, VertexLabels -> "Name"] & /@ t10]
```

or, (thanks: @halmir):

```
HighlightGraph[footballNetwork, t10, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

to get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: or you can just do HighlightGraph[footballNetwork, t10, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

Comment: @kglr what does the "& /@" exactly do?

Comment: Thank you @halmir. I updated with your suggestion.

Comment: @JakeFeuerman, see [Function (&)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) and  [Map (/@)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html)

Answer (score 2):

Associations are useful for such tasks.

```
footballNetwork = 
  ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "AmericanCollegeFootball"}];

asc = AssociationThread[
   VertexList[footballNetwork], 
   EigenvectorCentrality[footballNetwork]
   ];

Graph[footballNetwork,
 VertexLabels -> Thread[Keys@TakeLargest[asc, 10] -> "Name"]
 ]
```

Comment: I figured it out, sorry :) `VertexLabels -> {i -> "Name", j -> "Name"}`